# What is the delay time between each poll

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In kafka documentation i'm trying to understand this property **max.poll.interval.ms**

> The maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer group management. This places an upper bound on the amount of time that the consumer can be idle before fetching more records. If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member.

This mean each poll will happen before the `poll-time-out` by default it is 5 minutes. So my question is exactly how much time consumer thread takes between two consecutive polls?

For example: Consumer Thread 1

First poll--> with 100 records
          --> process 100 records (took 1 minute)
          --> consumer submitted offset

Second poll--> with 100 records
           --> process 100 records (took 1 minute)
           --> consumer submitted offset

Does consumer take time between first and second poll? if yes, why? and how can we change that time ( assume this when topic has huge data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "take time between"; if you are talking about the spring-kafka listener container, there is no wait or sleep, if that's what you mean.

The consumer is polled immediately after the offsets are committed.

So, `max.poll.interval.ms` must be large enough for your listener to process `max.poll.records` (plus some extra, just in case).

But, no, there are no delays added between polls, just the time it takes the listener to handle the results of the poll.